# Word 2007 not counting first pages

Tags: microsoft-word, numbering, formatting

I am trying to write an essay which is a couple of pages long I have 10 pages including the first page but I want it to not say a page number on the first page and on the second page say  "Page 1 of 9" how do I reflect this behaviour in Word 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link from Microsoft with a few steps to follow:

[Remove the page number from the first page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/hp012276571033.aspx)

Another good link to follow that will give you some more advanced formatting tips for different sections:

http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/Page_Numbering.htm

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but there are linked duplicates to this question and this is a link-only answer.

Comment: The primary link appears to be dead, and I couldn't find an archived copy.  The 2nd link is useful but doesn't appear to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

you must do a new "section" starting on page two, then tell word to numbering the pages of the second section

Comment: This doesn't really address how to get the adjusted total pages.